# UIScrollView - set negative contentOffset when bounce animation starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, bounce

I am using a `UITableView` to achieve a scale/unblur effect on my user's profile picture (like in the Spotify App) when I pull down the `UITableView` to a negative `contentOffset.y`. This all works fine...

Now, when a user pulls down to a `contentOffset.y` smaller or equal to a certain value -let's call it `maintainOffsetY = 70.0`- and he "lets go" of the view, I would like to maintain this `contentOffset` until the user "pushes" the view up again, instead of the view to automatically bounce back to `contentOffset = (0,0)` again.

In order to achieve this, I must know when the touches began and ended, which I can do with the following delegate methods:

```
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // is like touches begin
    if ([scrollView isEqual:_tableView]) {
        NSLog(@"touches began");
        _touchesEnded = NO;
    }
}
- (void) scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
// is like touches ended
NSLog(@"touches ended");
if ([scrollView isEqual:_tableView]) {
    _touchesEnded = YES;
}
```

}

Then in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

I check if the `contentOffset.y` is smaller than or equal to `maintainOffsetY` and if the user has already "let go" of the table, so it is about to bounce (or already bouncing) back to `contentOffset = (0,0)`.

It does not seem to be possible to let it bounce back only to the `maintainOffsetY`. Does anybody know a workaround or have an idea on how to solve this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you find any solution regarding this issue?

Answer (score 4):

To set a negative offset to a scroll view you can use this.

You need to save the initial content inset of scroll view. It can be not 0 already, if you have translucent nav bar for example.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        contentInsetTopInitial = self.tableView.contentInset.top;
    }
```

Then write this.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset; // need to save contentOffset before changing contentInset
    CGFloat contentOffsetY = contentOffset.y + contentInsetTopInitial; // calculate pure offset, without inset

    if (contentOffsetY < -maintainOffsetY) {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInsetTopInitial + maintainOffsetY, 0, maintainOffsetY, 0);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.